# Is std::vector::size() allowed to require non-trivial computations? When would it make sense?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, std

I'm reviewing a piece of code and see a class where an `std::vector` is stored as a member variable and the size of that `std::vector` is stored as a separate member variable. Both `std::vector` and its "stored copy" of size are never change during the containing object lifetime and the comments say size is stored separately "for convenience and for ***cases when an implementation computes the size each time***".

My first reaction was "WT*? Should't it be always trivial to extract `std::vector`s size?"

Now I've carefully read 23.2.4 of C++ Standard and can't see anything saying whether such implementations are allowed in the first place and I can't imagine why it would be necessary to implement `std::vector` in such way that its current size needs non-trivial computations.

Is such implementation that `std::vector::size()` requires some non-trivial actions allowed? When would having such implementation make sense?

Comment: My assessment would be; I don't care which implementation we use, feel free to swap it for anything else. If you depend on the fact that it's a `std::vector` though, it'll probably always be inlined anyway, so yeah.

Comment: `size` is a const function, which among other things means it cannot possibly call any non-const functions such as for allocating memory or locking. As such, any non-trivial computation that it could possibly do is trivial anyway. In all likelihood, it simply returns the value of the size member, but even if it was to do some "complicated math" as in adding up the lengths of several sub buffers (which btw. is not legal for a vector, because data is guaranteed to be contiguous), the overhead would still be trivial.

Comment: @Damon - It could still calculate the answer to the ultimate question of life the universe and everything for each element and the divide the sum by 42 to get the size. I agree that there is a logical implementation. But sadly that does not prevent some people from writing code that's too 'smart' for us to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that your definition of "trivial" doesn't match that of the author of the code.

If `size` isn't stored, I'd expect `begin` and `end` to be stored, and `size` to be computed as the difference of the two, and that code to be inlined. So we're basically talking two (nearby) memory accesses and a subtraction, instead of one memory access.

For most practical purposes, both of those are trivial, and if the standard library author thinks that the result of that computation isn't worth caching, then personally I am happy to accept their opinion. But the author of that code comment might think otherwise.

IIRC the standard says somewhere that `size` "should" be O(1), not sure if that's in the text for sequences or for containers. I don't think it anywhere specifies that it *must* be for `vector`. But even if we read that as a non-requirement there's a fundamental QOI issue here - what on earth am I doing optimizing my code for such a poor implementation at the expense of normal implementations?

If someone uses such an implementation, presumably that's because they *want* their code to run slowly. Who am I to judge otherwise? ;-)

It's also *possible* that the author of the code has profiled using a number of `end-begin` implementations, and measured a significant improvement by caching the size. But I think that's less likely than that the author is being too pessimistic about the worst case their code needs to handle.

Answer (score 7):

C++03 says in Table 65, found in §23.1, that `size()` should have a constant complexity. (In C++0x, this is required for all containers.) You'd be hard-pressed to find a `std::vector<>` where it's not.

Typically, as Steve says, this is just the difference between two pointers, a simple operation.

Comment: Does it, though? I have never liked nor understood that note, "should have constant complexity". I agree it "should" be read as a requirement, though ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, it was unnecessarily confusing, and simply poor wording IIRC.

Comment: @GMan: as `AProgrammer` says (in a deleted answer), there's an issue with `list` and the version of `splice` that takes an iterator pair. As you say, it's just poor wording for the standard to create confusion w.r.t `vector` because of that.

Comment: It's defined here what "should" means: http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=10562502&objAction=Open&nexturl=%2Flivelink%2Flivelink%3Ffunc%3Dll%26objId%3D4230456%26objAction%3Dbrowse%26sort%3Dsubtype. See "Annex H", Table H.2 "Recommendation".

Comment: @Johannes to the rescue! Makes sense, then: that's where the leniency for `splice` came from.

Comment: @Johannes: I think we're agreed what it actually says. What's left is to debate whether in our opinion that's defect, and whether code should be written as if the "should" were a requirement. In particular, if `list` alone needs the complexity to only be a recommendation, and hence sequence does, then IMO it's bad interface design to fail to tighten it for `vector` and `deque`.

Comment: @Steve, I think I misremembered something with splice.  Looking at the C++98 standard -- so it isn't a change in C++0X --, the complexity of the case I though was problematic is marked linear (while other cases are constant).  I'll try to review more in depth later.

Comment: I thought they changed "should be constant" to "shall be (amortized) constant" or something. Could misremember this one, though.

Comment: @AProgrammer: ah, that's OK then. So possibly it's a straight mistake - historically they hadn't decided which of `splice` or `size` needed the exception, eventually they decided `splice` needed it but they didn't change `size`. Or possibly they were being cautious that they might in future introduce other sequences that need it, or were being permissive in allowing others to write such containers and call them "sequences".

Comment: @Johannes, there is no "amortized" in n3290 in table 96 (which has notes special casing `array<>` for other things, but none for list).

Comment: @AProgrammer ah, I think I was confusing it with table 101. It already said "amortized constant" in C++03, so I'm not sure what I was reading back then.

Comment: @Steve, I've just looked it up.  List::size from G++ is using std::distance and if I'm not mistaken is recomputing the size each time it is called (they probably can't change it until the accept to change the ABI).